# Background (parent form) should be editable when i click outside modal popup(dialog)

Tags: angular6

I am using NgbModal model for modal popup(dialog) in angular 6.
I have a parent form with button, when clicked onto that button it opens the popup.
so my requirement is, when modal pops up, the background (parent form) should be editable or clickable.

also when ever modal pops up the background should be in Editable mode.

i have tried  data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" properties to make the parent form editable.

but this doesn't work.

```
<button aria-label="matMenuButton" mat-icon-button (click)="open()">
    <mat-icon aria-label="menu" aria-hidden="false">picture_in_picture</mat-icon>
</button>

<div>
  <div class="modal-header">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

  </div>
<div>
```

component that opens :

```
open() {
        this.modalRef = this.service.openTest('Test View');
    }


openTest(title: string) {
    this.modalRef = this.service.open(TestComponent, { size: 'sm' });
  }
```

When ever the modal (dialog) pops up,

the background (parent form) should be editable always.

Comment: What does it mean that the background should be editable? You wanna be able to change any text on the page? Or just the form in the background?

Comment: yes. i want to edit text , text area, any control etc anything that is behind the pop up.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do that - you will always have backdrop. You could try something with CSS to resize the backdrop, but I'm not sure if it would work. Alternatively just create your own modal component for this.

Comment: ok. thanks Zlatko.

Comment: yes. creating custom would be better.

Comment: but in angularjs this is possible.

this is what we have used :
ng-popup - Angular modeless dialog without jQuery dependency

plugin : ngPopup

Comment: I don't know about something out-of-the-box, maybe Angular Material could be configured so. Alternatively you'll just have to write your own.